# LibGDX ScrollPane doesn't draw ImageButton

Tags: android, libgdx, imagebutton, scrollpane

I'm kind of new to the LibGDX API, and I was trying to organize labels and ImageButtons inside tables (and tables inside those tables). When I run the app, the ImageButtons are not being drawn onto the screen.

I've searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer, so I'd really appreciate help.

*EDIT: It might happen because I am using tables inside tables, but I didn't find anything about nested tables, or anything like that to be honest.*

I call a method in render to keep the labels' text changing that looks like this:

```
public void drawTable(){
    final Table scrollTable = new Table();
    scrollTable.addActor(canbtn);
    scrollTable.row();
    //other buttons

    Label.LabelStyle style = new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE);
    Label.LabelStyle style2 = new Label.LabelStyle(font2, Color.WHITE);

    CustomLabel amtLabel = new CustomLabel("" + (int)(game.tot.getSum()), style);
    CustomLabel mizcoins = new CustomLabel("Mizcoins", style2);
    CustomLabel mpsCount = new CustomLabel(game.totMPS + " MPS", style2);

    PerSec can = game.boosts.get("Can").getPerSec();

    Table t = new Table();
    t.add(drawer(can, canbtn));
    t.row();
    scroller = new ScrollPane(t);

    table = new Table(); //the container table
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.add(amtLabel).padTop(50);
    table.row();
    table.add(mizcoins);
    table.row();
    table.add(mpsCount);
    table.row();
    table.add(scroller).fill().expand();//.space(350).padBottom(10);
}
```

And the drawer() function:

```
public Table drawer(PerSec perSec, ImageButton imgbtn){
    Label.LabelStyle style = new Label.LabelStyle(font2, Color.WHITE);
    Label.LabelStyle style2 = new Label.LabelStyle(font2, Color.WHITE);
    Label.LabelStyle style3 = new Label.LabelStyle(font2, Color.RED);

    CustomLabel nameLabel = new CustomLabel(perSec.getType(), style);
    CustomLabel priceLabel = new CustomLabel("Price: " + perSec.getPrice(), style2);
    CustomLabel addsLabel = new CustomLabel("Adds: " + perSec.getDefAddPerSec(), style2);
    CustomLabel youHaveLabel = new CustomLabel("You Have: " + perSec.getAmt(), style3);

    Table mainTable = new Table();
    Table smallTable = new Table();

    smallTable.add(priceLabel);
    smallTable.row();
    smallTable.add(youHaveLabel);

    mainTable.add(nameLabel);
    mainTable.add(imgbtn);
    mainTable.row();
    mainTable.add(smallTable);
    mainTable.add(addsLabel);

    return mainTable;

}
```

Comment: A few things that pop out are: you first do "addActor" on the canbtn and then in "drawer()" you add it to something else. This overrules the previous add call because an actor can only have 1 parent. Also add and addActor do not work the same way. addActor places it as a child only. whereas add() creates a table cell where it is added to. making it use the table's alignment functions. The problem could be: overriding the add, adding it to the wrong table. Or adding it with a size of 0.

Comment: I couldn't quite understand what you were going for, because I think I'm stuck on what I think I did. I'll paste a link to show you what I was going for with the design: http://imgur.com/a/tpVnZ

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode to show you how I would go about creating such a table (as described in the image in your comment)

```
private void setupScrollPane()
{
    ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane(generatePanels());
    pane.setBounds(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    stage.addActor(pane);
}

private Table generatePanels()
{
    Table list = new Table();
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        list.add(genetePanel()).row();
    }
    return list;
}

private Table genetePanel()
{
    Table root = new Table();
    root.setSize(400,200);

    Table left = new Table();
    Table middle = new Table();
    Table right = new Table();

    left.add().growY().row();       //an empty row for padding
    left.add(new Label("Price label")).row();
    left.add(new Label("you have label")).row();
    left.add().growY().row();       //an empty row for padding

    middle.add(new Label("Name label")).row();
    middle.add().growY().row(); //an empty row for padding

    right.add(new ImageButton()).row();
    right.add(new Label("Adds label")).row();

    root.add(left).growX();
    root.add(middle).growX();
    root.add(right).growX();
}
```

Comment: Hey! First of all, thanks a lot. Now, I've tested your code and every time I load the screen is adds a duplicate of the first list to the screen, so essentially on the first load I have 2 items, then on the second 4, then 6 then 8 and so on... How do you get over that, and also how do you update it so that the "you have" and "price" labels change when you click on the ImageButton? Thank you SO MUCH, again...

Comment: Setup the screen in either a constructor or in a setup function. If you really want to do it in show(). keep a boolean that checks if it was already setup. which you can unset in dispose if needed.